# Modify table to add Partition syntax get error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning, alter-table

I tried the following code for table partitioning.

```
 ALTER TABLE activity_log(PRIMARY KEY (`activityId`)) 
   PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(dated) ) (
   PARTITION p20150101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-01-01')),
   PARTITION p20160101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-01-01')),
   PARTITION p20170101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-01-01')),
   PARTITION p20180101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-01-01')), 
);
```

**ERROR**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PRIMARY KEY (`activityId`)) 
>       PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(dated) ) (
>       PART' at line 1

**Existing Table Structure**

```
 CREATE TABLE `activity_log` (
 `activityId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `teamId` int(11) ,
 `addedby` int(11),
 `leadId` int(11),
 `activity` VARCHAR(255),
 `dated` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`activityId`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=496831 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What i am doing wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: Take `(PRIMARY KEY (activityId)` out

Comment: Getting this error `#1503 - A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function` to take out `(PRIMARY KEY (activityId)`

Comment: That's a different question and frankly, the error message is quite clear in this case.

Comment: Don't bother partitioning a table unless you expect at least a million rows.  About the only benefit in partitioning is to quickly purge 'old' data; is that your goal?

Comment: @RickJames Yes that's my goal. I have 20 millions records that i want to partition.

Comment: (The schema implied that you had no more that 496K rows.)  What benefit do you expect from partitioning?  There is _no_ intrinsic performance benefit, except in obscure use cases.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint